# PhantomJS not working on JavaScript page, error "Activate JavaScript"

Tags: javascript, jquery, bash, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS + wget to see page content (which is my goal) on a JavaScript page.

This is the command I use:

```
$ phantomjs save_page.js http://wzdig.pbc.gov.cn:8080/dig/ui/advsearch.action > page.html
```

save_page.js

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(system.args[1], function()
{
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

But the html shows "请开启JavaScript并刷新该页" which means "activate JavaScript".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: instead of example.com you need to provide real URL

Comment: sorry i copied from an example. Still not working with the actual page.

Comment: why do you mention wget if it's not used (at least here)

Comment: my first intention was to use either one of the two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See update below the line.**

The reason your example didn't work is the tricky target page that tests if the page is opened in a real browser that can do javscript. The first time the page is loaded your browser is given a javascript to execute. Then the second time the page is loaded the real page is shown.

But in your example the script exits right after the first page load.

A little bit better solution that doesn't rely on timeout of 3 seconds (connection to Chinese sites is often slow, we cannot be 100% sure 3 seconds is enough).

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

// Imitate a real browser
page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";

// Called every time a page is loaded
page.onLoadFinished = function(){

    // If the real page with search controls is loaded
    // then get page.content and exit
    var inputCount = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.querySelectorAll(".jfk-textinput").length;
    });

    if(inputCount > 0) {
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
    }

};

page.open(system.args[1]);
```

---

**UPDATE**

Ok, so you're probably after the results of the search. In this case you can change logic that decides that the page has loaded to this solution:

```
var inputCount = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelectorAll("h3").length;
});
```

...because the titles of the articles found are output with <h3> tags.

Comment: `gov.cn` that's the government's site! I believe 3s delay will be enough, but your code is also good!

Comment: @Igor You're probably right, but I like to imagine this sample might be used in another situation in the future, hence I try to make it a bit more durable. Your solution is also good because it's shorter and straight to the point of the question. BTW, thanks for the bounty, mate!

Comment: thanks to you and @Igor . But I've been trying to change the code for a specific search and It doesn't work. I assume I'll have to change the code in : `return document.querySelectorAll(".jfk-textinput").length;`  with for example the search. But it gets stuck thinking, so I assume it's not the correct code. This is the search: [ http://wzdig.pbc.gov.cn:8080/dig/ui/search.action?hl=zh-CN&sr=score+desc&q=%E9%93%81&rp=&advepq=%E9%93%81&advoq=&adveq=&ext=&advtime=2&advrange=text%26title] i tried changing   ".jfk-textinput" with value="铁" with no success.

Comment: did you try it? because it get stuck, like in a loop or something. Since there is no debug I don't know the reason. But it will be helpful to know if it works for you. Besides, accessing from my browser has turned in to a hell of time to wait.

Comment: Actually, there **is** debug, if you run phantomjs with `--debug` command switch. Also, try running it with `--cookies-file=cookies.txt` switch (before script) a couple times. There's no need to wait for more than 10 seconds I think. It worked for me the second time I ran it with --cookies-file

Comment: assuming the code is correct (just replaced ".jfk-textinput" for "h3) the command ends like this: `phantomjs --cookies-file=cookies.txt get.js 'wzdig.pbc.gov.cn:8080/dig/ui/search.action?hl=zh-CN&sr=score+desc&q=铁&rp=&advepq=铁&advoq=&adveq=&ext=&advtime=2&advrange=text%26title' > page.html
` If it's correct it still doesn't work. What could be wrong??

Comment: I'm new in here. Do you think I better open a new Question?

Comment: 1. Address should start with URL scheme: 'http://...' 2. Not sure what codepage is in your terminal, you probably should be better off hardcoding URL inside of your script (h3 selector is hardcoded anyway). 3. Don't write output to page.html yet, make it work in terminal first.

Comment: Yea! seems to work now! The only problem is that instead of the content from http://wzdig.pbc.gov.cn:8080/dig/ui/search.action?hl=zh-CN&sr=score+desc&q=%E9%93%81&rp=&advepq=%E9%93%81&advoq=&adveq=&ext=&advtime=2&advrange=text%26title it redirects me to http://wzdig.pbc.gov.cn:8080/dig/ui/search.action . Tried changing the search with the same result...

Comment: I'm glad it works in principle, now it's up to you to debug the script, figure out what the site wants and solve these little details. The redirect probably has something to do with the target site usage, not with the script itself. Still, have a look at what I've got: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/1S1vRAb.png)

Comment: what are you trying to say with the screenshot? I can access as well through the browser, that's why I think it has something to do with the script. Otherwise it wouldn't work on the browser...

Comment: The screenshot was made by PhantomJS 2.5 beta on Win 7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `userAgent`, this script works:

```
var page = require('webpage').create({viewportSize:{width: 1600,height: 900},
settings:{userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0',
javascriptEnabled:'true',
loadImages:'false'
}});
var system = require('system');

page.open(system.args[1], function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
},3000);
});
```